# Which Wave is leading?

Tags: power

In the figure below I think that the Purple wave leads the pink by 135 degrees. The reason is that at the zero crossing the purple wave crossed the x-axis to be in the positive y-axis whereas the pink is in the negative y-axis.

Right?

[image]

Comment: It might be lagging by 225 degrees. Sometimes that is important to know because it might tell you something important about the circuit if pink were created from blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one right answer to this question. The purple wave could be leading the blue one by 135˚ or it could be lagging behind by 225˚. The blue curve is just a standard sine wave, y = sin(x), and the purple curve could be described as either y = sin(x - 135) or y = sin(x + 225) because the two produce the same curve, due to the fact that sine has a period of 360˚.

Comment: Thanks. But, usually we consider the smaller angle of the two 135 and 225. Thus y = sin(x - 135) is the common answer. Right?

Comment: That is true, but it helps to have a sound knowledge of how they can both be true. Helps when simplifying equations in the future. :)